# Open all Children at once under a parent on click in D3 Js Vertical Tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to open all the children under a parent when I click on the parent

After clicking on 3rd parent it should open all the left and right children at once and if all children are in open when I click on parent it should close all.
In order to get left and right I made all the children under another  in nested JSON so I was able to get that left and right 
below is the code, I am using in d3js vertical tree

```
if (d.children) {
                    _callerNode = null;
                    _callerMode = 0; // Collapse
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else {
                    _callerNode = null;
                    _callerMode = 1; // Expand
                    if (d.parent.children && d.IC==="Yes") {
                      expand(d)
                    }
                    else{
                      d.children = d._children;
                      d._children = null;
                    }
                }
                update(d);
            });
        } else {
            if (d.children) {
                _callerNode = d;
                _callerMode = 0; // Collapse
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                _callerNode = null;
                _callerMode = 1; // Expand
                if (d.parent.children && d.IC==="Yes") {
                  expand(d)
                }
                else {
                  d.children = d._children;
                  d._children = null;
                }
            }
            update(d);
        }
```

when I click on parent it should automatically open left right children
There might be a chance I get more children left and right for parent 2 as well later

any help would be appreciated Thanks in advance for all the help

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a similar principle to the `collapse` function that you call when you initiate the chart, but this one will expand all the nodes instead. Here's the appropriate `expand` function (I've inserted into the code just below the `collapse` function):

```
        expand = function(d) {
            if (d._children) {
                d.children = d._children;
                d.children.forEach(expand);
                d._children = null;
            }
        },
```

And then you just need to call it at the appropriate time, which is during your `nodeclick` function:

```
                if (d.children) {
                    _callerNode = d;
                    _callerMode = 0; // Collapse
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else {
                    _callerNode = null;
                    _callerMode = 1; // Expand
                    // INSERT HERE!
                    // if the node depth is 2 or more, call the `expand` function
                    if ( d.depth >= 2 ) {
                      expand(d)
                    }
                    // otherwise, just do the standard node expansion
                    else {
                      d.children = d._children;
                      d._children = null;
                    }
                }
```

By the way, you have two very similar bits of code within a couple of lines of each other:

```
                    if (d.children) {
                        _callerNode = null;
                        _callerMode = 0; // Collapse
                        d._children = d.children;
                        //d._children.forEach(collapse);
                        d.children = null;
                    } else {
                        _callerNode = null;
                        _callerMode = 1; // Expand
                        if ( d.depth >= 2 ) {
                          expand(d)
                        }
                        else {
                          d.children = d._children;
                          d._children = null;
                        }
                    }
                    update(d);
                });
            } else {
                if (d.children) {
                    _callerNode = d;
                    _callerMode = 0; // Collapse
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else {
                    _callerNode = null;
                    _callerMode = 1; // Expand
                    if ( d.depth >= 2 ) {
                      expand(d)
                    }
                    else {
                      d.children = d._children;
                      d._children = null;
                    }
                }
                update(d);
            }
```

You could think about refactoring this so that you don't have this repeated code - e.g. make a new function:

```
function expandCollapse(d, caller) {
    if (d.children) {
      _callerNode = caller;
      _callerMode = 0; // Collapse
      d._children = d.children;
      d.children = null;
    } else {
      _callerNode = null;
      _callerMode = 1; // Expand
      if ( d.depth >= 2 ) {
        expand(d)
      }
      else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }
    }
    update(d);
}
```

and then replace the existing code with `expandCollapse(d, null)` or `expandCollapse(d, d)`.